# catch time when the user submit data when using blink c#

Tags: c#, time, timer

[image]
[image]
[image]

that is my interface which contain listbox of date, time and name. this interface shows that the time always changed but the other data remain the same.

data for the name is receive by user using a socket. anyway, where the data gets is not an issue here.

i set the data to be appear by blink, which i set the time to true. every time user sent data, it will automatically shows up. Here, we will know that new data been sent by user. if there is no new data sent, it should appear the old data or just an empty listbox.

however, the time is always change. it does not static.it keep on changing the time. i cannot get the specific time when we are receiving the data.

this is my code.

```
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        listBox1.Items.Clear();//date
        listBox2.Items.Clear();//time
        listBox3.Items.Clear();//level
        listBox4.Items.Clear();//name

        pictureBox1.Refresh();

        //retrieve date
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime saveNow = dt.Date;
        string shortDate = dt.ToShortDateString();
        //retrieve time
        int hours = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        int minutes = DateTime.Now.Minute;
        int seconds = DateTime.Now.Second;             

        for (int i = 0; i <= _server.Q.NoOfItem - 1; i++)
        {                
            String time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
            String words = _server.Q.ElementAtBuffer(i).ToString();
            String[] berjaya = words.Split(new char[] { ',', '[', ']', ' ' });                                               

            listBox1.Items.Add(shortDate);
            listBox2.Items.Add(time);
listBox4.Items.Add(berjaya[3]);//name
```

The data receive is being split to each own listbox.

After split the data and view in each listbox, i save all the data in the xml file.this is my code.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load("C:\\Users\\HDAdmin\\Documents\\SliceEngine\\SliceEngine\\bin\\Debug\\saya.xml");
                XmlElement contentElement = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Patient");

                XmlElement levelEl = xmlDoc.CreateElement("LevelPriority");
                XmlText xmlText = xmlDoc.CreateTextNode(berjaya[1]);
                levelEl.AppendChild(xmlText);
                contentElement.AppendChild(levelEl);
                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(contentElement);

                XmlElement nameEl = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Name");
                nameEl.InnerText = berjaya[3];
                contentElement.AppendChild(nameEl);
                xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(contentElement);
```

the xml file is put together in `for (int i = 0; i <= _server.Q.NoOfItem - 1; i++)`
im thinking of doing this.

```
    if(berjaya[3] != null){
       //put the code above
}
```

however, the time will still go on..my idea does not work. is there any way for this?

Comment: What do you mean by freeze? What are you trying to freeze?

Comment: Why not rename your `listbox1`, etc variables to something that make sense instead of having to put a comment beside them?!

Comment: @MatthewRz, what i meant is catching the specific time when the data receive. im using blink (it will appear the data submitted automatically)

Comment: How about every time you receive data you use `DateTime.Now` to get the date?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I don't get it ;|